# How can I add a jpanel to an jpanel that is on a jscrollpane when I click a jlabel?

Tags: java, swing

I have got a JScrollPane that is called `incomeScroll` and on this Scroll Pane is a JPanel that is called  `inscrollPanel`.
If the user clicks on the plus label

[image]

then a new jpanel should be added to `inscrollPanel`. I called revalidate and repaint on the `inscrollPanel` and on the `incomeScroll` Panel, but it did nothing. I designed the window with NetBeans UI Designer. And I tried different layouts such as BoxLayout and FlowLayout. The JPanels should be vertical aligned. You can see two jpanels in each jscrollpane and my question is how can I add another jpanel to `inscrollPanel` which is the child of `incomeScroll`?

Here is the code I put in the mouselistener when you click on the plus label so far:

```
`javax.swing.JPanel panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
 panel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(359, 149));
 panel.setBackground( new java.awt.Color( 119, 255, 144));
 inscrollPanel.add(panel);
 inscrollPanel.revalidate();
 inscrollPanel.repaint();
 incomeScroll.revalidate();`
```

Comment: and you are sure that the listener is being called? adding a `System.out.println("aufgerufen")` would help verify that (or use a debugger). `setBounds` indicate that you are using no `LayoutManager` - that;s not recommended and maybe your problem...

Comment: posted code is working when using the default `LayoutManager` (`JPanel` and `JFrame`). Maybe the problem is with rest of code... suggested (required?) to post a [mcve]

Comment: So I tried out basicly every layout and it did not work. I am using NetBeans UI Manager, so I have more than 1000 lines of code. That is the reason why I did not provide more code. The actionlistener works and when I am adding a jpanel to another jpanel it works too, but when I add a jpanel to a jpanel which is on a jscrollpane then it does not work.

Comment: `I have more than 1000 lines of code.` - You don't learn a new concept by playing with 1000 lines of code. You learn a new concept by playing with simplified code. So all you need is a JFrame with a JScrollPane and  and panel added to the scroll pane. Then you can add a button to the panel. When you click on the button you add an new panel to the existing panel. Total code will be about 20-30 lines of code. Then once you understand the basic concept you figure out how this code is different from your existing code.

Comment: `The actionlistener works` - a JLabel doesn't support an ActionListener. However, it is a good idea to use an ActionListener so instead of  JLabel you can Use a JButton. You can make the button look like a label by using: setBorder( null ), setFocusPainted( false ).  Also, you only need to revalidate(), repaint() the panel in the scroll pane.